# Highcharts multiple series

Tags: json, highcharts, series

I've got this JSON array:

```
[{"name":"test1","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,40.6],[1363388400000,35.7],
[1363820400000,41.24],[1364511600000,40.56],[1365112800000,38.96],[1365544800000,39.8],[1366063200000,40.58],[1366668000000,40.79],[1367272800000,38.06],[1368309600000,37.95],
[1368655200000,41.31],[1369346400000,40.16]]},{"name":"test2","data":[[1361574000000,0],
[1362006000000,1.46],[1363388400000,1.42],[1363820400000,1.42],[1364511600000,1.37],
[1365112800000,1.41],[1365544800000,1.41],[1366063200000,1.35],[1366668000000,1.45],
[1367272800000,1.36],[1368309600000,1.36],[1368655200000,1.36],[1369346400000,1.37]]}]
```

I believe this is a valid JSON format, correct?

Unfortunately only an empty graph is plotted using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('testdata.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title : {
                text : 'Test'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'Test',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get this working properly? I've read some Highcharts documentation, but I don't have enough programming experience to get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the debugger console or Firebug and search for probable errors if any . To test JSON , use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: The JSON seems valid (thanks), but what do I need to add to the code to plot the data?

Comment: Go to the [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) demo and look into its jsFiddle.

Comment: Your php returns correct format ? Do you use json_encode() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a series object with your json.

You are then specifying the entire series object as your data for your series.

You need to either build the json to only include the data array, or you need to specify

```
series:data
```

instead of

```
series : [{
                name : 'Test',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
```

Answer (score -2):

I would also check if you are returning the JSON in the first place from testdata.php by printing it out the json as well as checking if you included all the necessary files for high charts to work.